# How do 4-20 mA receivers work?

Tags: power-supply, current, 4-20ma

For a sensor device such as a positioner, do they sense 4-20 mA from two wires and supply from another two wires, or is this done with only two wires?
If only two wire, how can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite the title, your inquiry seems to apply more to the transmitter design. The receiver, after all, can just be a 250 ohm (or whatever) resistor connected to ground. The other wire would be connected to a power supply (often 24VDC) at the receiver end so that only two wires run to the transmitter.

For the transmitter, you have to design a circuit that draws a constant current from a supply that could be anywhere from (say) 8V to 24V. The constant current should depend on the sensor output. Often this involves putting a resistor in series with the low side of the output, creating a negative voltage with respect to the circuit ground.

Real transmitter designs often involve galvanic isolation and frequently (these days) also involve a processor, and some even modulate the voltage drop to send digital signals using the HART protocol. You can find a few canned chips for transmitters in TI's XTRxxx series (formerly Burr-Brown), however they are limited in functionality by the monolithic process (plus a depletion MOSFET often). Many, probably most, 4-20mA process control transmitters have magnetics in them.

Answer (score 5):

They are many loop powered sensors, so it is possible that you may need only 2 wires to the sensor. You have not included details to your sensor so it's hard to know what you have.

Providing the sensor consumes no more than 4 mA, it can be designed to be line powered. If it requires more than 4 mA then it must be locally powered (typically AC powered) and the 4-20 mA loop becomes simply the data loop.

These articles may help you:
This is a [basic article](https://www.predig.com/sites/default/files/documents/whitepapers/4-20_mA_Current_Loop_Fundamentals.pdf) on 4-20 mA loop technology
...and this is the [datasheet](http://www.ctconline.com/datasystemmedia/DAT10029.pdf) for a loop powered vibration sensor.

Typically the receiver is also the location of the loop power supply (the sensors are the remote part), so the receiver will have both loop and power wires.

Comment: for example, if I want to receive my signal with rcv420, How can I use my signal line as a power line?

Comment: Actually the real limitation is the power that can be derived from the maximum allowable voltage drop at 4mA. If you allow a 15V voltage drop, that's 60mW, so 50mA at @1V is not out of reach.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany. Very true if you are willing to put a DC-DC convertor in.

Comment: @rashid. Look at the datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/rcv420.pdf  ....Figure 8/9 give examples of using the local power to power the loop and potentially the sensor.